# OpenCV - OutOfMemory with big dataset

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am working with OpenCV2.4 and SVM classification and I need to load a big dataset (about 400Mb of data) in C++.  I've been able to save this dataset under a XML file, but I am unable to load it after that.  Indedd, I receive the following message :

> OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 408909812 bytes) in OutOfMemoryError, file (my opencv2.4 directory)modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, line 52 - error: (-4)

How could I increase the available memory (I have plenty of free RAM) ?

Thanks a lot !

EDIT : 
Here is the place where the problem appears. The code works when I load a smaller file

```
  std::cout<<"ok 0"<<std::endl;
  FileStorage XML_Data(Filename, FileStorage::READ);
  XML_Data["Data"]>>m_Data_Matrix;
  XML_Data.release();
  std::cout<<"ok 1"<<std::endl;
```

EDIT 2 :
Problem solved : the solution was to compile my application and OpenCV2.4.5 as a 64 bit application.  I've installed a 64 bit version of MinGW, build OpenCV with this new version (and using cmake to configure) and then modified the compiler used by codeblocks.
You could find these links usefull : http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=13016.0 and http://www.drangon.org/mingw.

Comment: Small code snippet will be helpful, I think.

Comment: One potential reason of this error: somewhere you have a memory leakage.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think it is a leakage problem : the problem is my dataset is too big for the allowed memory.  My question is : how can I modify this allowed memory ?

Comment: I have no enough information to help you.
Please, try to watch out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596990/whats-the-graceful-way-of-handling-out-of-memory-situations-in-c-c.
Bad advice: try to create a 64 bit application, it can utilize much more memory.

Comment: It was the good solution.  It works now :-).  Thanks !